# Opening iTunes radio stream

Tags: c#, com, itunes

I am creating a application in C#, I am using iTunes COM object to access iTunes properties.

I am able to play video files and Audio files by programmatically setting up their path, but when I'm trying to access Internet URL stream for podcast and radio it's not working as intended.

```
    iTunesAppClass objITunesAppClass = new iTunesAppClass();   
    objITunesAppClass.OpenURL("http://www.abirock.ca");
```

Is it possible to access internet online streams? If yes how?

Comment: What return value do you get? They're defined at http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/interfaceIiTunes.html#z5_3

Comment: so finally it worked out this way....
The thing needed to pass here is the IP Address like this instead of the web address obj.OpenURL("http://108.166.161.205:8795");